# 500 Internal Server Error with Wamp and Magento

Tags: magento, wamp

I am stuck at accessing the installation page, can't seem to get it to work, it always gives me a 500 Internal Server Error error.

I have looked into some of the similar question solutions but they didn't work.

Comment: To start with, you should enable developer mode and check your error logs

Comment: I don't know how to enable developer mode, I am actually a noob to using Wamp, here is the error log:
https://i.imgur.com/bI2RLRF.jpg

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Following error you have given in your post's comment should lead you to the solution after a little search.

The problem is Magento's .htaccess file consists `<IfVersion>` command.

In order to use this feature **mod_version** module should have **enabled** on your Apache web server. Otherwise it will give 500 error.

In Wamp it is **disabled by default**.

To enable it in Wamp you can do following steps:

1. **Find your apache config file (httpd.conf) :** It usually is under /wamp/bin/apache/apache(version)/conf/httpd.conf
2. **Open the configuration file with your favourite text editor:** You can simply use Notepad. But I suggest any other one since notepad sometimes doesn't show line breaks. It will be more readable if you do (e.g. Notepad++)
3. **Search the following text:** "mod_version"
4. **You will see following line:** `#LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so`
5. **Uncomment it, so it will become enabled:** Simply delete **#** sign to uncomment it
6. **Left Click on Wamp and press Restart All Services:** Since you have made changes in the configuration file in order to let Apache server know about the changes you should restart at least Apache server.

Now you can check if Magento is working. If it isn't check the error log again. There might be another issue.

Following 6 steps should easily solve the error that you have provided in the comment. Also, please edit your post and add more details e.g. error log.

Comment: Okay, now I get this message after I open Magento page:

"Magento supports PHP 7.0.2, 7.0.4, and 7.0.6 or later. Please read Magento System Requirements"

Comment: Never mind it was easier than I thought, I just picked the newer version from WAMP PHP settings, thanks for this great answer.

Comment: @eyups this really helped me fix the annoying issue, thanks for this constructive answer.

Answer (score 0):

If first time issue after installation, probably You must enable the Apache mod_rewrite and mod_version modules, simply uncomment strings in file httpd.conf(LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so and LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so ) save and restart server.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html
Apache 2.2 or 2.4
In addition, you must enable the Apache mod_rewrite and mod_version modules. The mod_rewrite module enables the server to perform URL rewriting. The mod_version module provides flexible version checking for different httpd versions. For more information, see our Apache documentation.