# Error 500 when start install Magento 2 in my server

Tags: magento, magento2

I start install Magneto 2 in my server.

And i see this error :

`Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at root@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.`

Where is problem ?

Comment: Please see the reference link below. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49393285/500-internal-server-error-with-wamp-and-magento

Comment: @HassaanAlvi the mod_version is active in my server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to enable error reporting inside app/bootstrap.php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

this will show you an exact error,

second check your database connections,

third check file permissions

UPDATED :

as per @jas said, also enable developer mode for easier debugging sessions

Comment: To add to the answer, enable developer mode for easier debugging sessions.

Comment: do one thing! put `index.php` file on your root with some echo statement, if still its not working then you have to contact your hosting provider for the same. This type issue many of us are facing now a days on linux hosting